# PDFLib equivalent to lineheight in css

Tags: pdflib

Is there a equivalent to the lineheight in css?

I have tried `wrap={lineheight={0 20}}` as an optionlist for `fit_textflow`

Answer (score 3):

with the option `leading` you can specify the distance between lines.

Please see PDFlib API reference, chapter 4.2 "Text Filter and Appearance Options", Table 4.6 for more details as well PDFlib 9 Tutorial, chapter 6.2.1 "Font and Glyph Metrics", section "Glyph metrics" for an introduction in this topic.

> The *leading* (line spacing) specifies the vertical distance between the baselines of adjacent lines of text. By default it is set to the value of the font size.

Comment: Hey. This is exactly what I'm looking for but for text extraction using TET. Any idea how to get this value?